# update value not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lokijs

I'm trying to perform update on a value but ,the new value that am assigning to it bound to scope value but does not change ,when I edit ,it save with the original `empty` value 
breakdown

```
$scope.showDepositUpdate = function(birthday) {
        $scope.depositValue="one";
        $scope.birthday = birthday;
        $scope.action = 'deposit';
        $scope.isAdd = false;
        $scope.showUpdateModal = true;
    };
$scope.updateDeposit = function() {
            $scope.birthday.Name = $scope.depositValue;
            StoreFactory.updateBirthday($scope.birthday);
            $scope.depositValue='';
            newValue =""
            $scope.showUpdateModal = false;

    };
```

but `scope.depositValue` does not update it according to value on the view , it always `concat` to "", here is my view

```
<form class="form-inline" ng-show="showUpdateModal">
            <h2 class="title">{{ action }} Birthday</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="birthday.Name" placeholder="name" placeholder="Jane Doe">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="depositvalue" placeholder="name" placeholder="deposit">
            </div>
            <button ng-click="updateDeposit()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-rounded">Save</button>
  </form>

<tr ng-repeat="birthday in birthdays">
            <td>{{ birthday.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ birthday.Date }}</td>
            <td> <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-rounded" ng-click="showDepositUpdate(birthday)">deposit</button>
```

Comment: Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example

Answer (score 1):

In your function `$scope.updateDeposit` you are stting up the value of the variable depositValue to "". `$scope.depositValue='';`. Maybe this is your problem?

I've done a snipet to show you that.

See if it is what you want.

```js
var $scope = {};

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

var StoreFactory = {
  updateBirthday: function(){return true} // JUST A MOCKUP
};

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.showDepositUpdate = function(birthday) {
      $scope.depositValue = "one";
      $scope.birthday = birthday;
      $scope.action = 'deposit';
      $scope.isAdd = false;
      $scope.showUpdateModal = true;
    };
    $scope.updateDeposit = function() {
      $scope.birthday.Name = $scope.depositValue;
      StoreFactory.updateBirthday($scope.birthday);
      $scope.depositValue = '';
      newValue = ""
      $scope.showUpdateModal = false;

    };

  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <form class="form-inline" ng-show="showUpdateModal">
    <h2 class="title">{{ action }} Birthday</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="birthday.Name" placeholder="Jane Doe">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="depositvalue" placeholder="deposit">
    </div>
    <button ng-click="updateDeposit()" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-rounded">Save</button>
  </form>

  <tr ng-repeat="birthday in birthdays">
    <td>{{ birthday.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ depositvalue }}</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-rounded" ng-click="showDepositUpdate(birthday)">deposit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try a console.log() of the value in your Factory? Whats the value there?

I once had such a problem and that was because (referred to your problem)

```
$scope.birthday.Name
```

is just a reference to `$scope.depositValue` and so you pass a reference to a function that is changed quite after function call (`$scope.depositValue = ''`).
Would be good to know what `StoreFactory.updateBirthday($scope.birthday);` actually does.